# If np-complete problems are the hardest problems in np, why are there multiple np-complete problems?

Tags: np

If np-complete problems are the hardest problems in np, why are there multiple np-complete problems?

How can there be multiple hardest problems?

Is it like the top 10 hardest problems hard np-complete?

Are np-complete problems the hardest types of problems?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: I know how it works. I ask a question, it gets mark as duplicate for no reason. Then I have to make another account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If np-complete problems are the hardest problems in np.

The definition of an np-complete problem is: [If a problem is NP and all other NP problems are polynomial-time reducible to it, the problem is NP-complete.](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/unsolvableProblem.html)

> Why are there multiple np-complete problems?

There are multiple np-complete problems because people have found multiple problems comply with the definition of NP-complete problems.

> How can there be multiple hardest problems?

There are more problems that are polynomial-time reducible to each other and are NP.

> Is it like the top 10 hardest problems hard np-complete?

The criterium isn't the top 10 hardest, but they should be NP, and all other NP problems have to be polynomial-time reducible to them.

> Are np-complete problems the hardest types of problems?

I think that minimally [unsolvable problems](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/unsolvableProblem.html) are harder.